# session_start() fails when loading php file from jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am including a php file into JQuery, like this:

Main php file:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<?php

$_SESSION['ID'] = "32";

?>

<div id="sesion"></div>

<script>

$("#sesion").load("fun.php");

</script>
```

php file that will load, fun.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
echo 'new php';
echo $_SESSION['ID'];
?>
```

fun.php shows blank as soon as I add session_start() if i remove it, it will display:"new php"

I need to open session in the "fun.php" file, but I can't seem to achieve it.

Comment: both files will require `session_start();` **before any other output**

Comment: Since you've provided no code, we can provide no help. Have you done ANY basic debugging yourself? Perhaps you've got errors/warnings in the script which prevent the session_start() from actually executing because of "headers already sent" errors. But that's a just because, as I said, you've provided no actual code.

Comment: @MarcB there's lots of code, but I think I provided the necessary information. The $("#Chalk").load('chalk_element.php'); is called from a js file within the header tags. index.php already has session_start()

Comment: no. you've provided "doesn't work". That's not useful at all.

Comment: I already did  @l̕aͨŵƦȆ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝ƞCͭ̏ȇƇhƐȓ0nè

Comment: PD reasons for downvotes ? I provided a clause that could be read and understood, bad for you if you can't understand a paragraph of real words. I updated my question to "more code" which wasn't event more code. Don't judge because you don't know to understand what you read. @MarcB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an encode problem when I saved the files. I saved both files in ANSI code and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Put `session_start()` at the top of the page that is including `chalk_element.php` within it's page

Comment: thanks @Vector, I already did include session_start() within chalk_element.php, it's also included within the index.php

Comment: if you have `session_start()` at the very top of `index.php` and at the very top of `chalk_element.php` then there's very little further assistance that can be offered without seeing the code to troubleshoot further.

Answer (score 0):

Try simplifying your environment.

Create a new index.php with `session_start()` at the very top, then create a couple of session vars.

Next, create your chalk_element.php file and load it via jQuery in index.php.

Now do something very simple to access a session var and see what happens. This will give you a simplified test environment where you can experiment with the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your outputting something (HTML) before the point you call `session_start`. You can either move `session_start()` so it's at the top of the page (right at the top, no whitespace) or call `ob_start()` first. You can then output data and call `session_start()` later.

Also, check your error logs for any useful error information as to why the PHP file has just stopped working.

Comment: every session_start() is before anything, I made sure of that too

Answer (score 0):

Both files will require [`session_start();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) at the top of each file before any other output as this function sends out several HTTP headers.

### Here is a simple example:

**index.php**

```
<?php 
//Start session
session_start(); 
//Set the value in your session
$_SESSION['key']='value';
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script>
$(function() {
   $("#Chalk").load('chalk_element.php');
});
</script>

<div id="Chalk">Loading...</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**chalk_element.php**

```
<?php 
//Start session also to `resume` session
session_start(); 
//Check from ajax
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) === 'xmlhttprequest'){
    //output session var if set
    echo isset($_SESSION['key']) ? $_SESSION['key'].' was set in session' : 'session value was not set';
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This One..!

> ob_start(); //top of the page
>
> ob_flush();//end of the page